# OpenCart simple paypal checkout

Tags: ajax, paypal, checkout, opencart

I have a client who is using OpenCart v.1.5.2.1 and they have one shipping method (flat rate) and one payment gateway (PayPal Standard).  They do not need nor want customer registration, and they just want PayPal's checkout to handle the shipping address.  How do I disable pretty much everything in OpenCart's checkout system, so that when a customer adds something to the cart and then goes to checkout, it takes them straight to the PayPal payment gateway?

Comment: I've been trying to implement this suggestion, but I can't get the ajax to load the payment steps that remain once I take the shipping and registration steps away....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747327/how-to-automatically-select-checkout-options-in-opencart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the views.  I figured it out, using a combination of javascript auto-click commands and css `display: none;` on the appropriate divs.