# Opencart : How to disable "Delivery Method" tab on checkout page

Tags: php, opencart

i am new to opencart and one of my client wants to disable that delivery method tab on checkout page.. I hide it by using css but it doensnt work.. Can anybody help me.. Thanks!! The site is  http://www.futsales.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747327/how-to-automatically-select-checkout-options-in-opencart

Comment: The answer provided in the link above should definitely solve Your problem. I'll mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

this vqmod should help you - http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=49258

it disabled the delivery method, so the billing and delivery details are always the same.